# What is the difference between using in possessive adjectives and possessive pronouns structures?

Tags: possessives, possessive-pronouns, possessive-adjectives

What is the difference between using in possessive adjectives and possessive pronouns structures?

For example:

> You car is faster than **my car**. (possessive adjective)

Versus

> Your car is faster than **mine**. (possessive pronoun)

As I understand, both are the same, but I don't know what's more common or what less common in such contexts, or maybe I should avoid one of them. I want to sound fluent.

Answer (score 2):

Pronouns in general exist to avoid repeating the same name or noun over and over when there is not a need to repeat it, and they also indicate that you expect the reader/listener to have paid attention and be part of the conversation.

So *mine* would be more usual and natural.

However, *my car* would be used if it's not obvious that you are comparing a car to a car, or if the speaker wants to be really clear to make sure he/she is understood.